# How to set AutoLayout in Custom cell By Programmatically in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

[image]

I want to Give 5px as a bottom Section By default, In second image it's working properly when size of Subtitle increases it's size automatically increases. But in first image it's size not increases.

As I have given constraints to image as height width and leading and top, title (apple). But Not working.

Comment: you want to set 5px from bottom to images of all cell ?

Comment: actually i have done autoresizing by adding constraints,

Comment: yes By Default it will be 5px from Bottom of image @BadalShah

Comment: thne just set bottom space in your custom cell to 5px. i think not need to set it programatically.

Comment: Actually i don't want 5px when size of subtitle increases..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the IBOutlet of **Bottomlayoutconstrain** of **imageview** as seen in below image.

[image]

And just set below line when subtitle size increase,

```
self.imageviewbottom.constant = label.contentSize.height; //Setaccording to your requirement like, 2.0
```